# Xamarin iOS: How can I set the property OptionStartDelayKey under CBCentralManager?

Tags: ios, xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

My devices advertises periodically every minute and I'm trying to call connect at that minute advertisement. I would like to set OptionStartDelayKey to delay my connect request until my device advertises. How can I set this property?

Expecting connect request to be sent out based on the delay value I set it.

Under public class CBCentralManager : CBManager
//
// Summary:
//     To be added.
//
// Value:
//     To be added.
//
// Remarks:
//     To be added.
[Field("CBConnectPeripheralOptionStartDelayKey", "CoreBluetooth")]
[Introduced(PlatformName.MacOSX, 10, 14, PlatformArchitecture.All, null)]
[Introduced(PlatformName.iOS, 11, 2, PlatformArchitecture.All, null)]
[Introduced(PlatformName.TvOS, 11, 2, PlatformArchitecture.All, null)]
[Introduced(PlatformName.WatchOS, 4, 2, PlatformArchitecture.All, null)]
public static NSString OptionStartDelayKey { get; }

Comment: Please post the relevant code

Comment: Just posted relevant property. It's under CBCentralManager and the property is OptionStartDelayKey

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation [ConnectPeripheral](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/corebluetooth.cbcentralmanager.connectperipheral?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) and [OptionStartDelayKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/corebluetooth.cbcentralmanager.optionstartdelaykey?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12), a NSDictionary should be created as an parameter to ConnectPeripheral. Try the following code:

```
CBCentralManager Manager;
Manager.ConnectPeripheral(peripheral, new NSDictionary
            (
              CBCentralManager.OptionStartDelayKey,new NSNumber(15)
            ));
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to set it but I'm not sure if it's working. Before I had a await sleep to pause before sending connect request and device advertises every 20 secs so most of the time I was able to hit it on the first advertisement. Now it doesn't seem as reliable. Sometimes it works but most of the time it's taking much longer. Is there a way to check to make sure the value is set or get debug logging to see when the connect request is actually sent out? I tried this but kept getting an exception: centralManager.ValueForKey(CBCentralManager.OptionStartDelayKey)

Comment: I thought using ConnectedPeripheral event to  detect whether device is connected might be helpful.

Comment: I have my app completed to connect and communicate with the device in foreground. Background doesn't work because of the await sleep so I'm trying to use this connect with delay to avoid using the await sleep. When I remove the await sleep and pass in the sleep secs. I'm not getting the same results. Taking much longer to get connected peripheral event in foreground. Wanted to see whatever value I set is actually set and being used.

Comment: I noticed that the same question has been asked at Microsoft Q&A. So let's focus on that thread.